# Using ngClass for only one element and not all elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

I am new to Angular. I am having a page where I have a registration form as a modal within the template and a success message or an error message is displayed within a separate modal. Depending on whether its a success or error, I am using ngClass to vary the background color of the modal, however this changes the background color of the registration form modal as well.

Please suggest how should I use ngClass so that it affects only the message modal.

I am using to following as of now:

```
[ngClass]="{'bg-danger': errorMessage, 'bg-success': successMessage}"
```

Comment: Are you sure you are applying the class to the message modal and not the registration form modal? Try providing more of your code so we can understand easier

Comment: @DanielT. No I am not, thanks for your reply. I have been asked to use alerts in place of modals, so changing it and deleting my question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have two of `[ngClass]="{'bg-danger': errorMessage, 'bg-success': successMessage}"`: 1. For the registration modal; 2. For the message modal.

Why do you have two when you actually need one, only for the message modal?

On the message modal html file you just need.

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Dialog with elements</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p [ngClass]="{'bg-danger': errorMessage, 'bg-success': successMessage}">
    Result
  </p>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
</div>
```

Here an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ab9mwq?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: I have modal on top of modal and only one of them concerns the success or error message. Besides, my question is different so kindly delete the answer as it does not tackle the question. Thanks